# Which setting does VS Code "Python: Enable/Disable Linting" command toggle, and where does it toggle it?

Tags: visual-studio-code

If I use the command palette in VS Code to toggle Python linting (via `> Python: Enable/Disable Linting`), does this correspond to any of the settings that I see in the Settings tab? It seems that toggling it via the command palette doesn't change any of the (many) "linting enabled" settings (see screenshot below).

Where is the setting stored which gets toggled from the command palette? And, which one takes precedence if they conflict?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From my experimentation, this command is only available when a workspace is opened in VS Code and a python file is open in the current editor, and it edits the workspace's `.vscode/settings.json` file (modifying the `python.linting.enabled` setting). In multi-root workspaces, it also makes the setting change in the `.vscode/settings.json` file of the root workspace containing the currently opened Python file.